How to integrate Clerk Authentication with ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API (SQL Server as database)
Whenever a user is registered / updated in my frontend app (which uses REACT) by clerk authentication, I want to store this details in my database too. For example if a user is created with certain info, then I need to store those user information in my database. For this I went through the official documentation, which uses webhooks, I could not find any information about an ASP.NET Core backend. Are we supposed to add something else in backend?
I've created a webhook in my clerk dashboard, triggering to this url https://74.225.241.169:7072/api/v1/User/profile, whenever a user is created or updated. But unfortunately nothing happened. (I haven't added additionally something related to clerk in my backend)
Response
